# What does the "1" state mean in OpenStack's web interface Horizon CSV Summary?

Tags: openstack

In OpenStack's web interface Horizon, under `Project Overview` we can `Download CSV Summary`:

[image]

---

What does state `1` mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'State' field in your CSV summary should match the 'vm_state' field in your database (I've checked MySQL db). Please check with nova client status of your vm's. If you see '1' somewhere, you need to check the corresponding field in your database. If not, maybe the value is not transformed correctly inside one of the Horizon view functions. In such case you should describe how to reproduce the problem and someone with development skills may debug it for you. It also looks like a vm migration problem.